# Enrichment analysis for suicides in former Bachelor contestants

Tags: statistical-significance, fishers-exact-test

First, forgive me if this is a nonstandard question; I haven't posted on StackExchange before, so I don't know the etiquette.

I have heard speculation that former contestants from the US show The Bachelor are enriched for suicide (two former contestants have committed suicide). I want to explore whether the Bachelor former contestant suicide rate is higher than the US background rate, and I'm not sure how to approach the problem. I first thought to simply do a Fisher's exact test of bachelor contestants (20 seasons x 25 contestants = 500 total contestants) and suicides against the total US population and the US national suicide count over a period of 20 years. However, the probability of a former contestant suicide increases over time due to the increased number of contestants and the additional time since the end of the show -- a contestant has had more time to commit suicide the longer it has been since he/she has been on the show. The US population size also increases with time, but at a much slower relative rate than former Bachelor contestants.

What would be a reasonable approach to look for an enrichment in former Bachelor contestant suicides vs. the US national background? Thanks.

Comment: (Egads, has that show been on for 20 years?) Note that the producers of shows like that specifically look for flaky, unstable people because they believe it makes for more interesting TV. In other words, it is quite possible the rate of suicides for former contestants is higher than the US population, but that the effect of having been on the show is irrelevant.

Comment: This is a data-generated hypothesis. You can't meaningfully test it on the same data that led to the hypothesis.

Comment: Oh sure, gung; I'm not trying to draw a particular causal hypothesis. I just want to know if there is a reasonable way to look for an enrichment in the dataset.

Comment: I'd guess the first thing to do would be to look at suicides per year since they were on the show (e.g. contestant A on show 10 years ago still alive, contestant B died of non-suicide cause 5 years after being on the show, contestant C committed suicide 7 years after being on show = 1 suicide in 22 years of follow-up, hazard rate 0.04545...). If one can get rates/y (or over other times) for the US population (possibly split by key predictors - e.g. age or gender might matter), one has something to compare to. But as Glen_b says, the cases that triggered the question will skew the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, Glen_b and Björn. The Bachelor case was brought to our attention because of the high suicide rate, which might be high by chance. We've unconsciously selected for an extreme case, and now we're trying to ask why it's extreme from an analysis of that case alone, without the ability to perturb the ostensible underlying suicide-generative system in a controlled way. 

Would it be fair to use the Bachelor to hypothesize that competitive dating reality shows are enriched for suicides and then to analyze suicide rates in Bachelor-comparable post-reality-show populations?